# Disable HTTP trace in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to turn off HTTP trace method via .htaccess using this directive?

```
TraceEnable Off
```

When I try to add this directive in .htaccess I get an internal server error, maybe it's only allowed in my main httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this directive isn't allowed in `.htaccess` as per [**official docs**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#traceenable):

```
TraceEnable Off
```

You need to put this in Apache config or your vhost setup.

In `.htaccess` you can use a workaround (as per the link shared by @donald123):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Hi i have added it but when i do cross checking i get 500 error. I dont have direct access to apache as i am using ibm bluemix

Comment: @rupesh: You need to contact your server admin to get details from Apache error file for 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

take a look on this http://www.ducea.com/2007/10/22/apache-tips-disable-the-http-trace-method/ it should be a solution for you